# C# Interface IEnumerable Any() without specifying generic types

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have casted

```
var info = property.Info;
object data = info.GetValue(obj);

...

var enumerable = (IEnumerable)data;

if (enumerable.Any())  ///Does not compile
{
}

if (enumerable.GetEnumerator().Current != null) // Run time error
{
}
```

and I would like to see if this enumerable has any elements, via using Linq Query Any().  But unfortunately, even with using Linq, I can't.

How would I do this without specifying the generic type.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While you can't do this directly, you could do it via `Cast`:

```
if (enumerable.Cast<object>().Any())
```

That should always work, as any `IEnumerable` can be wrapped as an `IEnumerable<object>`. It will end up boxing the first element if it's *actually* an `IEnumerable<int>` or similar, but it should work fine. Unlike most LINQ methods, `Cast` and `OfType` target `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`.

You could write your own subset of extension methods like the LINQ ones but operating on the non-generic `IEnumerable` type if you wanted to, of course. Implementing LINQ to Objects isn't terribly hard - you could use my [Edulinq project](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/) as a starting point, for example.

There are cases where you could implement `Any(IEnumerable)` slightly more efficiently than using `Cast` - for example, taking a shortcut if the target implements the non-generic `ICollection` interface. At that point, you wouldn't need to create an iterator or take the first element. In most cases that won't make much performance difference, but it's the kind of thing you *could* do if you were optimizing.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use [`foreach`, as noted in IEnumerable "Remarks"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2). It also provides details on the additional methods off of the result of GetEnumerator.

```
bool hasAny = false;
foreach (object i in (IEnumerable)(new int[1] /* IEnumerable of any type */)) {
    hasAny = true;
    break;
}
```

(Which is itself easily transferable to an Extension method.)

Comment: is that really the only approach?  Suprising. Seems like a big hack

Comment: @IlanKeshet Not the "only" approach. It is also not really a "hack", given what the IEnumerable interface exposes.

Comment: Surely not a Hack, quite a valid way to enumerate through the `IEnumerable` and check various conditions

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt to use `GetEnumerator().Current` tried to get the current value of an enumerator that had not yet been moved to the first position yet. It would also have given the wrong result if the first item existed or was null. What you could have done (and what the `Any()` in `Enumerable` does) is see if it was possible to move to that first item or not; i.e. is there a first item to move to:

```
internal static class UntypedLinq
{
    public static bool Any(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        IEnumerator ator = source.GetEnumerator();
        // Unfortunately unlike IEnumerator<T>, IEnumerator does not implement
        // IDisposable. (A design flaw fixed when IEnumerator<T> was added).
        // We need to test whether disposal is required or not.
        if (ator is IDisposable disp)
        {
            using(disp)
            {
                return ator.MoveNext();
            }
        }

        return ator.MoveNext();
    }

    // Not completely necessary. Causes any typed enumerables to be handled by the existing Any
    // in Linq via a short method that will be inlined.
    public static bool Any<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => Enumerable.Any(source);
}
```